# Read client certificate container name

Tags: c#, certificate

I have installed a certificate on my computer and I'm trying to read the Container Name property. Is that possible and how?

```
public void Read()
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
        {
            //Find Container name?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
public static void Read()
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
    {
        //Find Container name?

        var privateKey = mCert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        var uniqueKeyContainerName = privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
        var keyContainerName = privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
        var ProviderName = privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

More info about `CspKeyContainerInfo` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.CspKeyContainerInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

Comment: I've set a custom private container name on my certificate, but it now looks encrypted (or I cant find it). Is it suppose to work like that or how can I manage to decrypt it?

Comment: @emptyman Could you explain a little more? I don't understand what you are trying to do. IMHO I answered your previous question correctly.